# How write a query to put all values from a column into a string (transform column to row)?

Tags: sql, oracle

if here is the data column:

```
+----+-------------+  
| id | data        |  
+----+-------------+  
|  1 | max         |  
|  2 | linda       |  
|  3 | sam         |  
|  4 | henry       |  
+----+-------------+
```

so how to make a query then has a result:

```
"max, lina, sam, henry"
```

Much like a column to row transform. Above just a simple demo, may have 10000+ record on `data` field.

Comment: what version of oracle?

Comment: @J W, it's 11g, but will be perfect to compatible with 10g as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 11g, use `LISTAGG`

```
SELECT LISTAGG("data", ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "id") "data"
FROM TableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81c2c/3)
- [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm)

Comment: an alternative for 10g http://www.dautkhanov.com/2010/08/listagg-alternative-in-10g.html

Comment: @J W Thumbs up for the great answer. One more question, if I get `result of string concatenation is too long` from oracle, is there any way to over come such limitation instead of using `WHERE rownum < SOMESMALLNUMBER`?